# Date given "mmyy". How do I convert this into a date?

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

For example, 0519 is the date given. mmyy. How do I convert this into a date? Preferably mm-dd-yyyy. TIA!

Comment: What day of the month do you want to use when you convert it to a date?

Comment: That's not a date, so it can't be converted into one. A date has a month, day and year.

Comment: Default day of date: 15